# EXC BAD ACCESS when writing C code in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, c

I am trying to achieve some functionality using pure c programming language in ios app. The code runs fine when the square matrix size is 50(w=h=50). If I increase the size of matrix to 100, I get EXC BAD ACCESS message. Below is the code I am using:

```
    double solutionMatrixRed[w][h];
    double solutionMatrixGreen[w][h];
    double solutionMatrixBlue[w][h];
    double solutionMatrixAlpha[w][h];

    for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
        {

            //NSLog(@"x=%d y=%d",x,y);
            solutionMatrixRed[x][y] = 0;
            solutionMatrixGreen[x][y] = 0;
            solutionMatrixBlue[x][y] = 0;
            solutionMatrixAlpha[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Even if w=h=100, the total size should be 100*100*8 Bytes which 80KB, which is normal. Can anyone tell what could be wrong ?

Comment: The problem is not in this portion of code.Like you see x is always less than w, and y less than h.

Comment: Have you tried to allocate your arrays on the heap instead of on the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code allocates all four matrices in the automatic storage<sup>*</sup>, which may be limited. Even four times 80K may be too much for a mobile device.

If you need to deal with that much memory, consider allocating it from the dynamic memory using `malloc`:

```
double (*solutionMatrixRed)[h] = malloc((sizeof *solutionMatrixRed) * w);
// allocate other matrices in the same way, then do your processing
free(solutionMatrixRed); // Do not forget to free the memory.
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Often referred to as "stack", by the name of the data structure that is frequently used in the implementation of automatic storage.

Comment: If I want to initialise each entry in solutionMatrixRed to zero, can i simply write solutionMatrixRed[x][y] = 0 and iterate using two for loops, outer for loop for x and inner for y.

Comment: @user1464587 Absolutely - take a look at an example [here](http://ideone.com/j0FBV).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the stack size in iOS is limited to 512 KB.  At w = 100 and h = 100, your arrays would require about 312.5 KB.  I suspect that you are exceeding the stack size and should attempt at allocating the arrays on the heap (use malloc() to allocate the arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to allocate all that memory on the stack.
while you should allocate it on the heap, using dynamic allocation (malloc):

```
double **solutionMatrixRed = malloc(h * sizeof(double *));
for(i=0; i<h; i++)
    solutionMatrixRed[i] = malloc(w * sizeof(double));
```